# Django mapping user to model

Tags: python, django, django-models

On Django 1.9, I can create users through a user form view. When the user submits the form to create a profile, the submission can be seen in the admin under `Users` and is logged in fine. I want the user to only be able to view the models they have uploaded. As such, I need to map them together. However, the user model is not defined in `models.py`.

I have tried to link them in `models.py` in my model with:

```
user = models.ForeignKey(User)
```

However, this error is thrown:

```
NameError: name 'User' is not defined
```

Is this due to not having the user as a model in my `models.py`?

Request that creates user:

```
def post (self, request):
    form = self.form_class(request.POST)

    if form.is_valid():
        #creates an object from the form
        #being stored locally as of now
        user = form.save(commit=False)

        #cleaned data
        username = form.cleaned_data['username']
        password = form.cleaned_data['password']
        user.set_password(password)
        #Saved to the DB after it's shown in the correct format
        user.save()
```

`models.py`:

```
class Clean(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank = False)
    #User doesn't see when creating model
    cv = models.TextField(max_length=10000, blank = True, null = True)
    cvfile = models.FileField(validators=[validate_file_extension])
    #User doesn't se when creating model
    cvscore = models.IntegerField()
    spellerrors = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank = False)

    *** user = models.ForeignKey(User) ***
```

Any resolution would be appreciated. I am using Python 3.6.4.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are probably lacking an `import` statement, but nevertheless, referencing to `User` directly is typically *not* a good idea, since later, you might change the model you use for users.

Like the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/auth/customizing/#referencing-the-user-model) says, you should use the `AUTH_USER_MODEL` settings:

```
from django.conf import settings
from django.db import models

class SomeModel(models.Model):

    user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL)
```

Comment: Yeah it was an import error. Thank you. I assume I can then limit visibility by: cvs = Clean.objects.filter(user=request.user) ?

Comment: @Yunter: indeed, unless of course you do too much magic, but without much strange settings, this filter should work.

Comment: Thank you. I have ticked your answer. Is there an import I need for request?

Comment: @Yunter: no the request is typically a parameter in the view.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to use the `auth.User`, you should import it from django

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class Clean(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
```

or, use it like a `string` from the Django app `auth`

```
user = models.ForeignKey('auth.User')
```

Comment: Thank you. I forgot to add the import.